# Arduino not reacting from rasperry pi serial communication

Tags: python, c, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm really confused.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that needs to communicate to an Arduino Nano by using its `GPIO` pins `RX & TX` this is working fine except for a logic issue that I cannot figure out. I have a simple java web interface with 2 buttons, namely on and off, this interacts with a python script that needs to issue commands to the Arduino and it needs to either turn on or turn off a relay depending on the command it receives. By printing the `state` the arduino receives does reflect what the arduino should do (On button sends on command and Off button sends off command)

But, when I click a button the list below happens,

1. Click the On button - nothing happens

   Click the Off button - relay switches on

   Click the Off button - nothing happens

   Click the On button - nothing happens

   Click the Off button - relay switches off

I printed the state of the pin to which the relay is connected and its state does weird stuff,

1. On - state = 0 (No switching)
2. Off - state = 1 (Switching)
3. Off - state = 0 (No Switching)
4. On - state = 1 (No switching)
5. Off - state = 0 (Switches)

It makes no sense, here is what's happening from the python script

```
import serial
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
    


 
@app.route('/light/on')
def lights_on():
    line = serialComs(b"on\n")
    return redirect('/' + str(line))


@app.route("/light/off")
def lights_off():
    line = serialComs(b"off\n")
    return redirect('/' + str(line))


@app.route("/<line>")
def lights(line):
    print("The Light Is Now " + line)
    return str(line)

def serialComs(state):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600 , timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    ser.write(state)
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    return line
```

For the Arduino I have the following

```
#define relayPin 8
String command;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();
    if(command == "on"){
      turnOn();
    }

    if(command == "off"){
      turnOff();
    } 
  }
}

void turnOn(){
  print();
  if (digitalRead(relayPin) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  }  
}

void turnOff(){
  print();
  if (digitalRead(relayPin) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
  }
}

void print(){
   Serial.println("Pin State: ");
   Serial.print(digitalRead(relayPin)); 
   Serial.println();
}
```

Initially I had this, and used a USB cable for communication and it worked perfectly

```
#define relayPin 8
String command;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();
    if (command.equals("on")) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    }
    else if (command.equals("off")) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

I used this tutorial to configure the raspberry to allow serial communication by means of GPIO

[https://github.com/Arijit1080/Raspberry-Pi---Arduino-Serial-Communication[tutorial][1]](https://github.com/Arijit1080/Raspberry-Pi---Arduino-Serial-Communication%5Btutorial%5D%5B1%5D)

and in this I did everything that the `instructions.txt` specified, namely

```
1. sudo nano /boot/config.txt

        dtparam=spi=on
        dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
        core_freq=250
        enable_uart=1
        force_turbo=1
        
2. sudo cp /boot/cmdline.txt /boot/cmdline_backup.txt
3. sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt

    dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
    
4. sudo reboot

5. ls -l /dev

    sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service

6. sudo apt-get install minicom

7. minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0
```

And this is how everything is wired up

[image]

What could the problem be?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in the software?

Comment: And why do you read the pin before writing? Just set it to the desired state?

Comment: @Lundin I'm reading the pin first as I thought that the state was mixed up somehow, so I wanted to see what its state was before manipulating it, but this is not the case, and I don't know what the problem is, whether or not it's code, config, wiring... this is why I'm posting the issue

Comment: How/where is the button de-bouncing done?

Comment: @lundin there is no de-bouncing, the relay is triggered via software, I have a java app that makes an API call to the python script, there is no physical button that gets pressed

Comment: Ah ok. Btw I don't know this Arduino String class, is it like std::string? Because you do `command.equals("off")` in one place but `command == "off"` in another place.

Comment: @Juraj no sorry, its the wrong nano in the picture, I'm using ATmega328P

Comment: Divide and conquer: Check each of the subsystems on their own. Check that the Arduino runs correctly by connecting it to a terminal instead of your Python script and send your commands manually. If that is OK, it must be the Raspi. Connect it to a terminal instead of the Arduino and check that it sends the correct commands. And so on...

Comment: Its supposed to be `command.equals("off")` but it doesn't work properly either way

Comment: Nano resets on new USB connection. put some printing into setup()

Comment: relayPin is configured as OUTPUT. What exactly happens when you read it?

Comment: @user58697 When I isolated each system, `digitalRead(relayPin);` returned 0 or 1 depending on its state and it did reflect correctly, its when both of the systems are connected that it still returned 0 or 1 but it did not match the state of the relay

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the relay is the main problem, when I give it a `HIGH` signal, the coil does not stay energized until it receives a `LOW` signal as my previous relay does, instead, I need to send a pulse signal if you will, when I do the following it seems to work as expected

```
#define r 8
String command;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  command = Serial.readStringUntil("/n");
  command.trim();
  if (action.equals("switch")) {
    digitalWrite(r, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(r, LOW);
  }
}
```

When I send a command `switch` it energizes the coil and releases it again, this causes the relay to switch, when I send the same command, it then switches back. As mentioned, the coil doesn't stay energized so that I can see what state it's in.

I only need to figure out a way to get some sort of status back to see what the relay is doing.